# Are Non-Compete Agreements void if you beat your former employer to market?

Tags: startup

I have a friend working at my previous company that is something of a domain expert in a very specialized business area of a non-IT related nature.  He has been toying around with an idea and doing market research for a groundbreaking idea for a software tool that could potentially prove disruptive to this entire industry in this specific domain.

Biding his time he has been working on this silently and saving some money up, preparing a business plan and what not. An unfortunate turn of events happened to him recently where he discovered that he is being requested for interviews as a subject matter expert for another department in the company that is primarily focused on developing and building profitable software solutions.

Someone in this department somehow has a primitive form of this groundbreaking idea and they are hoping to start a new project to implement it, using my friend to fill in all the holes in their business plan as well as the holes in their technical knowledge to implement it correctly.

From what I understand they do not want to bring him into any kind of ownership stake of this as he is just an employee.  They don't want anymore of his involvement than him to just answer questions and be interviewed by analysts so they can extract all of this information that he has worked very hard on building thus far.

Without tipping his hand, he tried to plead with his boss that he wants no part of this but this has suddenly become a critical priority project for the company and his boss is powerless here.

He is considering leaving his job so that he can pursue VC or an investor to try and rush something to market before his current company.  He has a very good chance as I know that this software development department is very arrogant and like to think they are on the level of Google, but they historically perform very poorly, however they do have incredibly deep pockets and are led very ruthlessly by executives that are willing to spend whatever it takes to eliminate competition or "land grab".

He is concerned that when he started he isn't sure if he actually did sign a Non-Compete agreement or if this can be used against him if he attempts to start his company after leaving.

If he leaves the company immediately, starts his company and beats his former employer to market, does the typical Non-Compete Agreement carry any weight?  I am not looking for a legal answer but what in essence and spirit a Non-Compete Agreement actually means when you sign it?

**UPDATE:** I missed an extraordinarily important part of this question.  The department HE works for is technically considered a SEPARATE COMPANY.  He doesn't technically work for the company that has this software development department but they are under the same Non-Profit umbrella.  I wonder if he did sign a Non-Compete, if it even applies to the business endeavors of a "sister-company" that is highly linked with his non-profit company?

Comment: You're not looking for a legal answer? You should. You can get everyone's opinion on this and it will be nothing more than their opinion. In something as important as this seek legal advice.

Comment: No compete agreements are usually there for the benefit of the company. As such the're typically worded to gain maximum benefit for the employer, with minimum benefit from the employee. 
They _may_ not be legally enforcable though...

Comment: Essence/spirit of an NCA is to prevent employees from doing exactly what "your friend" is considering doing.

Comment: What country are you in? Did he sign a non-compete, or didn't he? If so then what did it say? If he did sign one then what makes him  (or you) think it would be invalid if he gets his product to market first?

Comment: @AE United States. He didn't have to sign one when he first started, but then he *might* have signed one to accept a promotion they offered him. They are trying to actively find opportunities to force employees to sign them where they didn't at hire date. He doesn't remember if he did sign it or not because it would have been a while ago before he started working on his business idea.

Comment: @maple_shaft, he needs to be clear whether or not he signed one, and if he did then what it said. This may involve him asking his work for their copy of it. He won't be able to get any meaningful legal advice - or meaningful advice of any kind - if he's not clear what he signed or even whether he signed it.

Comment: Please see my update

Comment: Short answer: it completely depends on the state and what he's signed, and he needs to seek legal assistance.

Comment: If he is valuable to the company, he could use that as leverage - if he thinks his idea will make them a lot of money, he could ask for equity.

Comment: Does he have any proof of the timing of his invention?

Comment: I'm voting to close, as this is *DEFINITELY* the domain of attorneys.  Tell your friend to find one.  The most relevant case that came to my mind was Mattel, Inc. v. MGA Entertainment, Inc., but your friend needs an IP attorney YESTERDAY!

Comment: The problem that the "essence and spirit" of a non-compete agreement is to completely shaft the employee to the employer's benefit. Yes, if a "ruthless" (as you put it) employer can use it to prevent the employee leaving the company immediately they hear the company is working on something they reckon they can do better on, and beating the employer to market, they will use it that way. Since they wrote it, that's part of the spirit of it. No employee *actively wants* a non-compete clause except as a means to the end of getting the job at all. So the letter of the law is everything, I'm afraid.

Comment: In a lot of states, non-competes aren't valid in court, period.

Comment: also "I am not looking for a legal answer" doesn't make any sense as the concept of 'non-competes' is *purely* a legal concept.

Comment: As much as people constantly advise "see an attorney", the reality is that it is RARELY done and for good reason: it is expensive, almost always a disappointment, and usually not necessary.

Answer (score 20):

> I am not looking for a legal answer but what in essence and spirit a
>   Non-Compete Agreement actually means when you sign it?

While you indicate that you are not looking for a legal answer, that's the only answer with any real meaning here. Anything else is speculation at best, and myth/legend at worst.

A Non-Compete Agreement is a form of contract and sometimes contracts mean whatever they say, sometimes whatever a court says.

Your friend should tread carefully here, and really needs legal advice before quitting or pursuing VC or other investor dollars.

> Are Non-Compete Agreements void if you beat your former employer to
>   market?

Maybe, maybe not - it depends on the specifics of the Agreement.

And remember, no matter what your interpretation, people can spend a lot of time and money defending a lawsuit - even if they end up winning.

> The department HE works for is technically considered a SEPARATE
>   COMPANY. He doesn't technically work for the company that has this
>   software development department but they are under the same Non-Profit
>   umbrella. I wonder if he did sign a Non-Compete, if it even applies to
>   the business endeavors of a "sister-company" that is highly linked
>   with his non-profit company?

Yet another reason to have a competent professional look over his non-compete agreement, and all other contracts before making such an important decision.

Comment: "contracts mean whatever they say" Not really. Many clauses in contracts can be invalid/unenforceable, especially in employment contracts.

Comment: Employment contracts are often filled with unenforceable garbage.  The *only* way to know is to talk with a lawyer in your jurisdiction.

Answer (score 12):

Another thing that should be considered here is ownership, which would actually stop things before you even get to decisions about a non-compete.

Many employment agreements for tech companies include language that states any ideas/developments you have while in their employment are owned by the company.  These can be sticky court cases and your friend absolutely needs real legal advice.  If his employment agreement does in fact include this language, then leaving to start his own company could be construed as theft of IP.

Bottom line, your friend really needs to get some good legal advice on all of the issues before he makes any decisions or takes any action.

Comment: It's also worth noting in some states these all encompassing agreements have been deemed unlawful while others they are ironclad. You really need to consult a legal advisor.

Comment: Absolutely, every state and every contract add their own little twist.  Almost always ends with lots of money in the lawyers' pockets.

Comment: And he might need to be prepared to prove he did NONE of the work on his idea while at work.

Comment: In some jurisdictions and contracts,  even that may not be sufficient. Very sticky business

Answer (score 7):

Considering what you say about the ruthlessness of the company, it would be a foolish and expensive move for him to try to do that. Even if they can't win, he would have to spend the money on lawyers and the time to defend and I suspect in a case like this, he could lose because this is exactly what non-competes are to prevent, someone taking his insider knowledge and using it to create a competing product. The fact that it hasn't gone to market yet would most likely be irrelevant since he gained the knowledge of what to create from his experience at the company and since his leaving the company could be shown as a reason for why their time to market got delayed.

From an ethical standpoint, it would almost certainly be the wrong move. It certainly violates the spirit of agreeing not to compete. From a practical standpoint, considering the potential cost of being sued and the destruction of his professional reputation that would almost certainly go along with it, it would be a wrong move. Further, potential clients in hearing that he is being sued might not want to buy his product since they won't know if he will still be in business. Legally, well you would have to ask a lawyer about that.

A far better move would be to come up with an idea that would not be in competition with them if he wants to leave and start his own company.

Comment: -1 - ethics? in a company? yuck. it technically isn't "ethical" to use someone to make X profit and pay them anything less than X.

Comment: @bharal companies exist to make a profit, why is that unethical (unless it is an outrageous profit and people are paid peanuts which is another discussion)? I wasn't talking corporate ethics, but personal ethics.  If he agreed not to compete, it is unethical to abbrogate that agreement. Just because someone else or some other organization is unethical does not mean you should be. If he felt like they took his idea, he should have pointed out he was pursuing it in his spare time when they asked the first question. Since he didn't, the company will consider this theft of intellectual property.

Comment: Disagree. Overly generic non-compete clauses are unethical because they restrict competition and harm the society. That's why there are strict rules on what is enforceable in most legal systems. "he gained the knowledge of what to create from his experience at the company" <- that's like the majority of entrepreneurs.

Comment: THen you don't sign one. It is unethical to sign something as a contract that you don't intend to pay attention to. It is unethical to give your word and then go back on it. This has nothing to do with the content of the non-compete and everything to do with whther you are an ethical person or not.  And the ethical reasons are not the only ones to make this a bad idea. There are practical reasons as well as I pointed out.

Comment: "It is unethical to sign something as a contract that you don't intend to pay attention to" -- not sure what you mean by "pay attention to", but if you believe a clause to be unenforceable then I don't think it's unethical to sign it with the full intention of later preventing it being enforced. I mean, it's not *nice*, but then it wasn't nice of the employer to try to stick an unenforceable clause on you in the first place. They probably knew what they were doing and if they didn't, well, they wrote the clause and they screwed it up. While not unethical it's still risky though, as you say.

Comment: @HLGEM: Companies push unfair terms to employees abusing their power all the time, which is why these rules can be found world wide. Considering this I don't think it's fair to simply say "don't sign it then".

Comment: @EnnoShioji it's not really "overly generic" though, is it? He's a "domain expert in a very specialized business area" and his employer wants to develop software in that specialized area using his subject matter expertise. It could hardly be a more specific act of competition.

Answer (score 6):

> I am not looking for a legal answer but what in essence and spirit a Non-Compete Agreement actually means when you sign it?

Developing products (and relationships) is a painful, costly process. The spirit of Non-Competes is that you won't take the end result of that process to a new company, who will take advantage of the "free" lessons learned. I certainly wouldn't hold your friend at fault, and I expect many others would not as well. They didn't get the idea from the company. They didn't leverage any of the company's costly research to further their potential new company.

All that said, the other answers are correct - being "right" isn't always enough in the business/legal world.

If your friend really is that valuable to the product, and it really is that disruptive then they have all sorts of leverage to renegotiate their value to the company. There are different ways to monetize ideas/expertise.

Answer (score 4):

Lots of things are the deciding factors here.  The most important:

1) The non-compete agreement he signed
2) The state.  (If he's in California, he's in much better shape than most other states)
3) Does he also have an non-disclosure agreement?

He really needs to consult a lawyer to know for sure, but I know a lot of non-competes will be all encompassing of anything the company does.  This is likely hard to enforce for something like a Fortune 500.  For something in the < 200 employees range, it likely becomes harder for him to prove there was projects going on to which he was completely unattached, and therefore could not be breaking a non-compete.

I researched a bit while I was on the job hunt, and the truth is, there is definitely no silver-bullet on either side.  They are very much like a divorce, and mirror them in court: two sides get lawyers and try to reach an agreement out of court.

For what it's worth, the last company I worked for was based in Illinois, and went after an employee that broke the non-compete, and were successful, AFAIK.  I know that the non-compete for some employees was pretty ridiculous (I think 18 months, and not sure how the pay worked).  When we broke off from said company and set up our domicile in California, the non-competes were suddenly a non-issue.

Comment: We are in a ludicrously business friendly/employee screwed state.

Comment: Agreed.  What he should be doing: 1.  Find everything he signed with the company.  2.  Consult a lawyer ASAP.  Alternatively, give up the idea entirely.